# Why is my header selectable and the cell not editable

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, data-binding, nsoutlineview

I have two questions related to `NSOutlineView`:

1. Why is my Header selectable even though I tell it that it is  a Group (otherwise it would not have the "Hide" on the right:

   [image]

   ```
   // I am telling the view that the given item is a group by implementing
   -(BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isGroupItem:(id)item;
   ```
2. I am using a **view-based** outline and so I can't press Enter or click on a leaf to edit it. Is there a simple way (with the default *view-based* setup so achieve this functionality).

   Please note that I tried to achieve this by binding to `editable` on the given column. But the method is never called.

Comment: Don't know if it will help you but I got the same issue if I override `mouseDown:` on the subclass of my outlineview. Removing this solves the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least I was able to answer the first part of my own question.

I had to [implement](https://github.com/besi/mac-quickies/blob/master/OutlineView/OutlineView/AppDelegate.m#L65) the method like so in order to make the header unselectable:

```
- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView shouldSelectItem:(id)item{
    // Add your own logic here to determine whether a cell should be selectable 
    return ![self isHeader:item];
}
```

I have created a little sample project that does the following.

- Display a list of items
- Edit the items in a master-detail fashion
- Remove and add items
- Usage of bindings

Check out [besi/mac-quickies](http://github.com/besi/mac-quickies/) on github.
Most of the stuff is either done in IB or can be found in the [AppDelegate](https://github.com/besi/mac-quickies/blob/master/OutlineView/OutlineView/AppDelegate.m)

[image: screenshot]